# drawing number triangles in java

Tags: java

Write a program that prints a right triangle out of numbers. After each time a number is printed, the number should be incremented by 1. The program should also print a space character after each number.

I'm trying to get a program to work as follows:

Get a number from user, denoting the number of columns,

Check if the user input is valid (it should be greater than 1). If not print an error message "Invalid number of columns"

If the number is valid, print a right triangle having inputted number of columns and as stated above.

```
    1
    2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9 10
```

but I am getting

```
    1 
    5 6 
    9 10 11 
    13 14 15 16
```

code:

```
int k=1;
for(int i=1 ; i<=4 ; i++)
{
    for(int j=1 ; j<=4 ; j++)
    {
        if(j<=i)    
            System.out.print(k+" " );

        k++;
    }
    System.out.println();           
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting others to do homework for a lazy student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if is missing brackets

```
if(j<=i)
  System.out.print(k+" " );
  k++;
```

so it **always** increments `k`

it should be

```
if(j<=i){
  System.out.print(k+" " );
  k++;
}
```